# iPad application - Mirroring the app in airplay

Tags: ios, airplay

I've a kids application which is rich in graphics.
It don't have any videos in it. Only background audio will be there
It has some activities like counting numbers, reading alphabets etc.
Can I mirror the application in apple tv using airplay so that what ever they see on iPad app must be shown on TV also?
I googled a lot... but i couldn't find any code. But I read that its possible. Can some one guide in how to proceed with this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use AirPlay your application does not necessarily have to do anything special. AirPlay is built-into iOS, and any app or game can take advantage of it. The user simply has to double-tap the Home button, swipe to the left, press the AirPlay button and select the mirroring option. This works for all apps automatically, including video and sound.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But can I program such that, i specifically design a view to be shown in airplay tv? Means, my app view will be different from the one that is being shown?